# How can I remove a network interface from being listed in Linux?

Tags: linux, network-adapter, ifconfig

A software I use gets confused if there is `irda0` (or some other uncommon device) in the `ifconfig -a` output.

What is the easiest way of preventing that device from getting listed?

I'm looking for an answer that doesn't require removing or disabling device physically or permanently and no rebooting as well.

Answer (score 2):

All network interfaces will be listed in the output of `ifconfig -a`. To remove one you would need to unload its corresponding kernel module.

But in your case I'd try to use [ifrename](http://www.stylesen.org/ifrename_to_map_physical_interfaces_permanently) to make it look like a "normal" interface. But the better approach would be to fix your br0ken software which seems to choke on device names.

Answer (score 1):

To unload it unload the module:

```
rmmod $(basename $(ls -l /sys/class/net/irda0/device/driver/module |awk '{print $NF}'))
```